# GridBagLayout alignment

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am trying to place these buttons a bit upper, but i just dont know how. This is what i got so far : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NySxN.jpg . I really need some help with this GridBagConstraints, as i really don't get it, even with tutorials. One thing is the weightx/weighty.. no matter what that value it has (0.1-1) it does the same spacing. Second thing is that anchor, even if i set anchor to LINE_START they are still in the middle of the frame. And the last thing, the gridx/gridy setting these to 0 doesnt mean the first position is in the top left corner ? And how can i modify the size (width of a column ) ? I tried c.gridwidth = 3, but nothing.

```
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    JButton buton1 = new JButton("Buton1");
    JButton buton2 = new JButton("Buton2");
    JButton buton3 = new JButton("Buton3");
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    add(buton1, c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    add(buton2, c);
    c.gridx = 2;
    add(buton3, c);
```

Comment: *"I am trying to place these buttons a bit upper"* - I think you're going to need to be more descriptive....

Comment: More upper like half of the space between them and the frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. weightx. If you set the weight add fill HORIZONTAL to the same component.
   weigth defines how extra pixels will be distributed between components.
   Imagine horizontal flow. You have 3 buttons each 100 pixels preferred width but your containr has 500 pixels. The 500-300 pixels must be distributed proportion is the buttons weights.

If you set weights [1,0,0] all the 200 extra pixels are added to the button1.

If you set weights [2,1,1] 100 extra pixels are added to the button1 and 50 are added to button2 and button3.

Of course if they have filling HORIZONTAL or BOTH

2. Anchor. Add e.g. NORTHWEST to place the content in the left/top corner.

If you define horizontal fill (and x weights) the buttons try to fill all the horizontal space.

If you define verticla fill (and y weights) the buttons try to fill all the verticla space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that i am doing this tutorial: http://blue-walrus.com/2011/12/gridbaglayout-tutorial/  . I dont know how comes his panes are aligned to the left( glued to the left side of the frame ) When i am doing it , everything is displayed in the middle of the frame.

Comment: Just realized it was because of the weights . What if i set the frame size to like 600,400. What can i do the make the componets be displayed all of the frame ? not just middle ?